# Swift Random Float Fatal Error : no uniform distribution on an infinite range

Tags: swift, random, floating-point

I'm trying to generate a completely random `float` value, which should be pretty easy. However, it doesn't work, and by the looks of it maybe I'm the first person to come across this error ? I certainly can't seem to find any prior post about it.

This code :

```swift
let min = -Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
let max = +Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
let range = min...max
let random = Float.random(in: range)
```

Works until the last line, which fails, producing `Swift/FloatingPointRandom.swift:162: Fatal error: There is no uniform distribution on an infinite range`

However, the range shouldn't be infinite. Inspecting min and max or the range itself in the playground shows that the bounds are `-3.402823e+38` to `3.402823e+38`, neither of which are infinite.

What is going on ? And is there a proper way to do this that I missed ? Besides the following, which seems very convoluted for such a simple task :

```swift
let min = Float(0)
let max = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
let range = min...max
let signs : [Float] = [-1, 1]
let random = Float.random(in: range) * signs.randomElement()!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the current implementation of random number generation for floating point values — if you check out [`stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointRandom.swift:156`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f68647ac3940148ba99b19ffd62e2b2d8976daae/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointRandom.swift#L156) (right around where your error message points to), you can see where this limitation comes from:

```
let delta = range.upperBound - range.lowerBound
//  TODO: this still isn't quite right, because the computation of delta
//  can overflow (e.g. if .upperBound = .maximumFiniteMagnitude and
//  .lowerBound = -.upperBound); this should be re-written with an
//  algorithm that handles that case correctly, but this precondition
//  is an acceptable short-term fix.
_precondition(
  delta.isFinite,
  "There is no uniform distribution on an infinite range"
)
```

The code attempts to prevent generating random numbers if the bounds aren't valid, but doesn't adequately handle overflows. There's a [GitHub issue tracking this bug](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/51306), but it appears that it's been around for a while now — although there's a comment stating that this would be fixed for Swift 5, that fix hasn't been introduced.

It may be worth commenting on that issue, or raising this on the [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org), where engineers who could address the issue can see this.

---

In the meantime, your proposed solution should get you close enough, for some definition of "close enough": you'll get a random number within the range that you want, though the limitations of floating-point precision may affect the exact distribution of numbers you get out. Depending on your use-case, this may not really matter, but without knowing more, this may or may not work for you until a full fix is introduced.

You could also attempt to generate a random number within a much larger range than `[-1, 1]`, and scale it by a smaller amount, which may get you a more accurate distribution of values.